# Regular Expression for Pipe Separated Values

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for pipe-separated values in this format:

```
|NAME=jason,jacob|AGE=42|...|
```

This is slightly different from most of the pipe-separated regular expression questions here, as it needs to deal with a starting and ending pipe. Regex will be used in javascript if it matters.

I've tried the following regular expression, which doesn't seem to match (Ultimately, I don't need the "key", I just need to count the "values"):

```
.*?\|[\w+]=(\w+)\|
```

Edit: there can be multiple key/value pairs, not a limit of 2.

Comment: `\|\w+=([^|]+)`?

Comment: Maybe `/\w+(?=(?:,\w+)*\|)/g` will help? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CKHbL5/1). Then, `s.match(/\w+(?=(?:,\w+)*\|)/g).length`?

Comment: count the values means that there are 3 in total? `\|\w+=(\w+(?:,\w+)*)(?=\|)` https://regex101.com/r/Q4aRgr/1 Take the values from group 1 and split on a comma and count the total.

Comment: I think you're making this immensely harder for yourself by doing it in a single (complicated, error prone) regex! Why not just strip the leading/trailing pipe, then split on the remaining pipes?

Comment: Edited the example and explained there can be multiple types. And I need to count the values for each key/value pair, not just for all keys.

Comment: @Jason Did any of the answers work out?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count entries you can use this code:

```js
const text = '|NAME=jason,jacob|AGE=42|...|';
const result = Array.from(text.matchAll(/([^\=\|]+)\=([^\|]+)/g));
const count = result.length;

console.log('Count:', count);
console.log('Result:', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use 2 capturing groups and split group 2 on a comma to get the count of values.

```
\|(\w+)=(\w+(?:,\w+)*)(?=\|)
```

- `\|` Match a pipe
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word characters
- `=` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\w+(?:,\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars and optionally repeat `,` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group
- `(?=\|)` Assert a pipe at the right

Capture group 2 contains the values. You could get them using `(m[2].split(',')`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XevJ2K/1)

```js
const regex = /\|(\w+)=(\w+(?:,\w+)*)(?=\|)/g;
const str = `|NAME=jason,jacob|AGE=42|`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(`For key ${m[1]}: ${m[2].split(',').length} value(s)`);
}
```

Comment: You do not need `// This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }` because your pattern cannot match empty strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, copy pasting from regex101 code :-|